# Usual term for "back part of the tongue"

Tags: vocabulary

As English (oddly) uses "back of the tongue" to refer to its top surface, how can I refer to the back part of the tongue, opposite to the front part of the tongue where its tip is? "back part of the tongue" ?

Answer (score 3):

The top surface of the tongue has a front, a middle, and a back. You will find this terminology used, for example, in oral medicine and discussion of flavours.

> Excess bitterness in your beer is usually perceived on the back of the
>   tongue
>
> Median rhomboid glossitis is a condition that can affect your tongue
>   if you have oral thrush. It causes a red, smooth patch or lump to
>   develop in the middle of the top part of your tongue, which can be
>   sore.
>
> The front two-thirds of the tongue that you can stick out is called
>   the oral tongue

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, referring to the **surface** or the **top** of the tongue means the part of the tongue with the tastebuds on it.

The **back of the tongue** refers to the surface of the tongue near the throat, while the **front of the tongue** refers to the surface of the tongue near the lips.

The **underside** of the tongue is the part without tastebuds.